# Why isn't this pytorch model improving

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to start out making ML Models in PyTorch. I have some experience in Keras, and I was trying to move to a more popular framework. I made a MNIST model, and it doesn't seem to be training properly. The loss is negative, and when I get a report about how it's performing, I can see that the model isn't improving. I think it's a problem with my convolution or linear layers not being defined properly. I pasted my code below.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision


class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
                super(Net, self).__init__()

                self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,5,5)
                self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(5,10,4)

                self.fc1 = nn.Linear(160,120)
                self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120,84)
                self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84,10)

        def forward(self, x):
                x = self.conv1(x)
                x = F.relu(x)
                x = F.max_pool2d(x, (2,2))
                x = self.conv2(x)
                x = F.relu(x)
                x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
                x = torch.flatten(x,1)
 
                x = self.fc1(x)
                x = F.relu(x)
                x = self.fc2(x)
                x = F.relu(x)
                x = self.fc3(x)
                return x

net = Net()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum=0.05)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('~/files/', train=True, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),     
  batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
                        
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('~/files/', train=False, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
                        
                        
def train(epoch):
        net.train()
        for batch, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                output = net(data)
                loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
                print(loss.item())
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                if batch % 10 == 0:
                        torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'model.pth')
                        torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), 'optimizer.pth')
def test():                    
        net.eval()               
        loss = 0             
        num_correct = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
                for data,target in test_loader:
                        ouput = net(data)
                        pred = ouput.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
                        num_correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()
                print(num_correct)
for i in range(1,15):
        train(i)
        test()
```

Comment: You would need a `Logsoftmax` layer at the end to get the log-probabilities in your network. Or else you could simply use `CrossEntropyLoss` instead. Also [here](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/how-to-use-pytorch-loss-functions.md) is a good resource you could follow to understand the basics

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely give this a shot and see if it works.